# How to close android app from angular with capacitor

Tags: android, angular, capacitor

I am new to Capacitor. I have angular website with that i have implemented android app with capacitor. I couldn't able to achive the close app behavior when user tries to press back button. When i am on home page and if user tries to click back button multiple times app should be closed. This is not happening in my case may be I have implemented android backbutton click to handle navigation between the pages. Is there anyway we can close the app from angular code?

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, NgZone, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';
 constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
 }

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.registerBackButtonListener();
  }


  public registerBackButtonListener() {
    return App.addListener('backButton', () => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.executeBakAction();//handles the navigation bw angular routes/pages
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    App.removeAllListeners();
  }
```

Thanks